# Cakephp3 call ViewCell of a plugin into another plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a plugin named **IncMenus**. In this plugin I've created a ViewCell.

For Example in my **IncMenus/src/Template/View/Cell/MenuCell.php**

```
class MenuCell extends Cell
{
 public function display($menu){

    $menus = $this->Menus->find('all', [
        'contain' => ['MenuItems']
    ])
        ->where(['id' => $menu]);


    $this->set(compact('menus'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['menus']);

}

}
```

and in **IncMenus/src/Template/Cell/Menu/display.ctp**

I'm displaying this menu.

Now I have another plugin named **SiteTheme**.

In this plugin I want to access that MenuCell so in one of my element (**SiteTheme/src/Template/Element/header.ctp**)

I'm calling the cell as:

```
 <?= $this->cell('IncMenus.Menu', ['menu' => 1]); ?>
```

But It displays the following error:

[image]

So how to call a View cell of a plugin into another?

Comment: Sorry the plugin Name is IncMenus. It stil gives the error. I've updated the code.

Comment: Did you open a bug ticket @ https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues yet?

Comment: Is it an issue? Or i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You might have just forgotten to load the plugin properly (in your bootstrap), then it cannot be found of course.

Comment: The plugins are loaded. I've crossed checked my Bootstrap.php

Comment: Debug https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/CellTrait.php#L68 - there it splits by plugin and cell name.

Comment: What do you mean by split by plugin?

Comment: Read and understand the code, then debug it to find out why it does what, and then you will most likely find the source of the issue.
Also make sure your namespace declarations are correct, this is usually the root cause. Having tests for your (plugin) cells would reveal that by the way.

Comment: It is showing how the plugin name is split from the method  name it the parts of the parameter are 2. But i'm just calling the default methods so don't need to mention it.

Comment: Am I wrong or the correct path should be `IncMenus/src/View/Cell/MenuCell.php`?

Comment: Thanks @arilia That was the problem. It is fixed now.

Comment: How to use Component in Cakephp cells?